# JSON decode failed

Tags: json, perl

Following is the code snippet where I am observing error: "malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at"

Error observed is at the decode_json line. Can someone point out what is the error?

```
my $serverurl = "http://mycompany.net/rest/api/2/";

my $username        = 'my.email@domain.com';
my $password        = "mypassword\@2019";
my $i ;
my $test;

my $headers = {Accept => 'application/json', Authorization => 'Basic ' .encode_base64($username . ':' . $password)};
my $client = REST::Client->new();

my $idartinstance;
my $idartinstance1;

 if (!$idartinstance)
    {
        print " Trying to Connect to URL using REST client interface \n\n";
        $idartinstance1 = $client->GET($serverurl."serverinfo",$headers);

        $idartinstance = decode_json($idartinstance1->responseContent());

    }
```

When I print `$idartinstance`, I get this:

```
REST::Client=HASH(0x8682024)->responseContent()
```

Does this mean, it is not able to find REST client?

[EDIT] I have modified the script as below and no difference in the errors.

```
my $serverurl = "https://mycompany.net/rest/api/3/";
my $username        = 'my.email@domain.com';
my $password        = 'pf9fCdkGXmi4pMHiwIh74A0D';

my $headers = {Accept => 'application/json', Authorization => 'Basic ' . encode_base64($username . ':' . $password)};

my $client = REST::Client->new();
if (!$idartinstance)
    {
        print " Trying to Connect to JIRA using REST client interface \n\n";

        $client->GET($serverurl."serverInfo", $headers);
        print $client->responseContent();
        $idartinstance = decode_json($client->responseContent());
    }
```

Now I have used encoded password. Error is same: malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)"). Tried accessing "https://mycompany.net/rest/api/3/serverInfo" via web browser and able to get the details.

Comment: Assign `$idartinstance1->responseContent()` to a variable and log it. Figure out what it really is before wondering why it isn't JSON.

Comment: The error is that `decode_json` takes a string (in JSON format), but you're passing it a `REST::Client` object.

Comment: Why is `$idartinstance1` a separate variable? `$client->GET(...)` just returns `$client` itself.

Comment: I did modified the description by printing the value of "$idartinstance". Is this indicating it is not able to find REST client?

Comment: That sounds more like you did `print "$idartinstance1->responseContent()"`, not `print $idartinstance`. None of those are right. You should have removed `$idartinstance1` and done `print $client->responseContent();`. Note: No quotes!

Comment: `at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)")` means you passed an empty string (or undef)

Answer (score 2):

Once you get a response, you have to check that its what you want.

```
if( $client->responseCode() eq '200' ){
    print "Success\n";
}
```

You may also want to check that the content-type is what you expect. If it's supposed to be JSON, check that it is:

```
if( $client->responseHeader('Content-Type') =~ m|\Aapplication/json\b| ) {
    print "Got JSON\n";
}
```

Once you've established that you have what you wanted, pass the message body off to the JSON decoder.

```
my $data = decode_json($client->responseContent());
```

You might also try to catch errors where you should have valid JSON but don't. The block `eval` can handle that (and see the many sources of the proper employment of `eval` for its best use):

```
my $data = eval { decode_json(...) };
```

I find that I tend to get the wrong content in two situations:

- the wrong endpoint, from which a 404 handler returns HTML
- a captive portal, which also returns HTML

Comment: Response is not what we want(JSON). Now need to find whats wrong in getting response?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misreading [the documentation for the module](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client). From the synopsis there, the example that most closely resembles yours is the first one:

```
my $client = REST::Client->new();
$client->GET('http://example.com/dir/file.xml');
print $client->responseContent();
```

Notice, in particular, that this example does nothing with the return value from `GET()`. In your example you do the equivalent of this:

```
my $client = REST::Client->new();
my $resp = $client->GET('http://example.com/dir/file.xml');
print $resp->responseContent();
```

As it happens, although there is no documented return value from `GET()` [**Update:** I was wrong here - see the first comment - but the return value is really only intended for chaining method calls], it actually returns the object that it was passed, so your approach should work. But it's generally a bad idea to not follow the documentation.

So what is actually going wrong? Well, I'm not sure. As I said, your approach should (accidentally) work. But the error message you're getting tells us that what you're passing to `decode_json()` is a REST::Client object, not a string containing JSON. I don't think that's how your code should work. Perhaps the code you've shown us isn't actually the code you're running.

The best approach to debug this is to follow the advice from Quentin in the first comment on your question - print the value that you're trying to pass to `decode_json()` before passing it to the function. In fact, that's good general programming advice - originally write out your code step by step, and only combine steps once you know that the individual steps are working correctly.

Using your variable names, I think your code should look like this:

```
my $client = REST::Client->new();

# ...other code...

$client->GET($serverurl."serverinfo", $headers);

print $client->responseContent();

# And, only once you've established that
# $client->responseContent() returns what
# you expect, you can add this:

$idartinstance = decode_json($client->responseContent());
```

If the `print()` statement doesn't show you JSON, then [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56682895/edit) to add whatever is printed and we'll take a further look.

Comment: "*Each of these methods makes an HTTP request, sets the internal state of the object, __and returns the object__.*" It's [all documented](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client#Request-Methods).

Comment: print $client->responseContent(); did not print anything. But from the 'Content-Type' check I found that its not the JSON format what is expected there.

Comment: @ravi: *print $client->responseContent(); did not print anything* - this ties in with the error message ('character offset 0 (before "(end of string)"'). Your request is returning an empty string. So what response code do you get (try `print $client->responseCode()`)?

Comment: @ravi: HTTP 501 means [not implemented](https://httpstatuses.com/501) - *The server does not support the functionality required to fulfill the request*. So I guess you need to spend a lot more time debugging the request you're making and comparing it with the documentation for the API that you're calling.